# Neo4j cypher return Path with a specific format

Tags: neo4j, cypher, neo4j-java-api

I have a cypher query to return the shortest Path between two nodes.

I am using Java JdbcTemplate.

```
MATCH (nodeA),(nodeB), p = shortestPath((nodeA)-[*..15]-(nodeB)) "  //
                + "WHERE ID(nodeA) = {1} and ID(nodeB) = {2} RETURN nodes(p) as nodes "  //
                + ",relationships(p) as edges
```

My problem is that I have a Util method that do the mapping of the jdbctempate result. It only works when my cypher returns nodes suchs as :

```
RETURN { id : id(node), labels : labels(node), data: node } as node
```

Is there a way to make my initial cypher return the result in that format?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NODES returns a list of nodes, so you can use [UNWIND](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/clauses/unwind/) to unpack the list into a set of rows. So in your example...

```
MATCH (nodeA),(nodeB), p = shortestPath((nodeA)-[*..15]-(nodeB))
WHERE ID(nodeA) = {1} AND ID(nodeB) = {2}
UNWIND nodes(p) as n
RETURN { id : id(n), labels : labels(n), data: n} as node, relationships(p) as edges
```

You can use WITH + COLLECT to fold the nodes back into a list, and then perform the same operation on relationships if you need.